# Is there any way to use vuetable-2 as module without build step

Tags: vue.js, vue-tables-2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
<script type="module">
    import * as vuetable from '/vuetable-2-full.js'
</script>
</html>
```

I need to use vuetable-2 as module but when this page is run i got an error
"vuetable-2-full.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Vuetable')"

Comment: Why don't you want any build step?

Comment: i'm quite a beginner of this. You can correct me if i go wrong. I need to use vuetable-2 in existing project, I think build step could make an extra load and complexity to project.